# How do I group constraints within a view

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I have a view in Swift that I need to add constraints to. I would like to apply constraints to titles over an image, such that the titles stay in the same position relative to the image, regardless of screen size. I want to use labels for the titles so that I can Localise the app and the country names will therefor change. In Photoshop I would just group the items and the  transform them as a group, how do I do this in Swift?

[image: screen shot showing images and labels]

Comment: Control click the object you wanted to add constraints to and select the other object you want the constraints to be relative to. Select the type of constraint you want to add from the menu displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of constraining a Label to the top left corner of an ImageView. You control+drag from the Label to the edge of the ImageView, so that the ImageView becomes highlighted and IB indicates Image View in the bottom right hand corner of the ImageView.  If you drag too far, then the whole View will be highlighted, and IB will indicate View in the bottom right hand corner of the View.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]